# SQL Server wild card issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table (Calendar)

```
Date                      Remark
2010-01-01                Sunday
2010-02-01                Saturday
2010-03-01                Public Holiday
2010-03-01                Rose Day
2010-04-01                Valentines day
2010-04-01                Public Holiday
2010-01-01                Sunday
2010-02-01                Saturday
```

I want to select only those date which is not having Saturday and Sunday.

```
SELECT * FROM CALANDER WHERE REMARK NOT LIKE 'SATURDAY' OR Remark Not like 'Sunday'
```

I am executing this query but this doesn't help me.

Comment: You say SQL Server, so why you tag MySQL?

Comment: Why dont you use `!=` or `<>` instead of like since its an exact match or `NOT IN` clause?

Comment: `LIKE` without wild cards doesn't make much sense.`<>`

Comment: And if a date is both a Saturday and also a Rose day?

Comment: @Shahab Haidar. As jarlh said : Like without wild cards doesn't make any sense. You should use 'AND' instead of 'OR'. This is a very basic query. You should work on your basic SQL skill

Comment: As we can see, each answer followed a certain interpretation. Sample output would've probably protected against that.

Comment: @ITSGuru, give him [something](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) why don't ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use IN

```
SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE REMARK NOT IN('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be written as a `JOIN` too, dunno which's more efficient though:

```
SELECT *
FROM CALANDER
WHERE Date NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date
    FROM CALANDER
    WHERE Remark IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to work with regular expressions (wildcards) you should follow this approach:

Sunday and Saturdays are the only days that start with `S`, so your wildcard should look like: `'S%day'`, in query:

```
SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE REMARK LIKE 'S%day'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDates (
    [Date] DATE,
    Remark NVARCHAR(50)
    );
INSERT INTO MyDates VALUES
('2010-01-01',                'Sunday'),
('2010-02-01',                'Saturday'),
('2010-03-01',                'Public Holiday'),
('2010-03-01',                'Rose Day'),
('2010-04-01',                'Valentines day'),
('2010-04-01',                'Public Holiday'),
('2010-01-01',                'Sunday'),
('2010-02-01',                'Saturday');

SELECT *
FROM MyDates
WHERE Remark NOT LIKE 'Saturday' AND Remark Not like 'Sunday';
--Or Remark <> 'Saturday' AND Remark <> 'Sunday';
```

Results:

```
+---------------------+----------------+
|        Date         |     Remark     |
+---------------------+----------------+
| 01.03.2010 00:00:00 | Public Holiday |
| 01.03.2010 00:00:00 | Rose Day       |
| 01.04.2010 00:00:00 | Valentines day |
| 01.04.2010 00:00:00 | Public Holiday |
+---------------------+----------------+
```

Checkout the **[demo](http://rextester.com/XDD85035)**

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be AND, not OR.

Also, if you want to use wildcards, the wildcard for any character is %.

These small modifications on your query will return all the rows not having Saturday and Sunday as part of their Remark column :

```
SELECT * FROM CALANDER WHERE REMARK NOT LIKE '%Saturday%' AND Remark Not like '%Sunday%'
```